# React-Natiove Error on Android Emulator "null is not an object (evaluating 'blob.data') readAsText "

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

When I run my react-native code on Android studio, I am getting red screen on Android emulator saying the following:

null is not an object (evaluating 'blob.data')

```
readAsText
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13212:10
d

<unknown>
    ScrollResponder.js:405:6
dispatchEvent
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10746:10
setReadyState
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10481:6
__didCompleteResponse
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10326:13
emit

__callFunction

<unknown>

__guard

callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    ReactNativeART.js:61:3
```

How to fix this error ?

This is ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js

```
'use strict';

import type {ReactNativeType} from 'ReactNativeTypes';

let ReactNative;

if (__DEV__) {
  ReactNative = require('ReactNativeRenderer-dev');
} else {
  ReactNative = require('ReactNativeRenderer-prod');
}

module.exports = (ReactNative: ReactNativeType);
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code for this error?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a problem with an older version of react-apollo and apollo-client. I upgraded all my apollo-* pacakges to the latest version, and the error disappeared.